# MongoDb C# - Check if Any Object in Array has Field of Type

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection called `Cars`, which has `Car` documents.

Each `Car` has an array field called `FormData`.

Each object within `FormData` has a `Data` field, which should be an object but is incorrectly writing as a string in our app. My goal is to select all `Cars` where `FormData[i].Data` is of type `string`. However, I am only able to check one level at a time by specifying it via dot notation (e.g. "Check if the second `FormData` object contains a `Data` field of type `string"). I do this like so:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Type("FormData.0.Data", BsonType.String);
```

I looked at the [filter docs](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1.htm), and don't see anything I can use. Closest is:

```
AnyEq<TItem>(Expression<Func<TDocument, IEnumerable<TItem>>>, TItem)
```

but this seems useless in my case, since it would only allow me to check the DataType of `FormData[i]`, rather than the fields within `FormData[i]`.

P.S. - didn't find a good way to do it in raw mongo either:

```
db.cars.find( { "FormData.1.Data": { $type : 2 } } )
```

---

Edit: In response to the aggregate comment - good idea, I just remembered I have used it before to check specific subfields like below (and I can adapt it to the question I asked). Unfortunately, I am not sure how to use it from the C# driver:

```
db.cars.aggregate([{ $match: { 'FormData.Data.field2450': { '$type': 2 } } }], {cursor: { batchSize: 0 }});
```

---

Edit 2, requested `FormData` obj - `FormData` is directly inside each `Car` document, and can be an empty array or any length:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried building your query with [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)?

Comment: Hey titi23, thanks for the answer. I have (I will update question to show an example), but I am not sure how to do it with the C# driver.

Comment: could you post your object? as I made a test when string data when field was type object and pushed list of strings ther I got extra fields in arra to recognize that `{
        "_t" : "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]",
        "_v" : [ 
            "1aaaa", 
            "1nnn", 
            "1ssss"
        ]`

Comment: @profesor79 Sorry for slow reply - added it to question. FormData is directly inside each Car document.

Comment: @VSO no problem now I have more info -could you post car class as well?

Comment: are you going to replace this from string to field? it could be easier on mongo shell

Comment: @profesor79: Yea, I am just going to replace the string with that string converted to an object.  It was supposed to be an object but somehow got saved as a string when someone imported data.